# Get character type of each character in a string

Tags: php, arrays, string, split, character

Let's say I have a string like `A10-53 c` and I want to get the character type of each character in an output array.

Something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => string
    [1] => number
    [2] => number
    [3] => symbol
    [4] => number
    [5] => number
    [6] => space
    [7] => string
);
```

I could make something like:

```
$str = 'A10:53 c';
$arr = str_split($str);

$str_length = count($arr);
$res = array();
for($i=0; $i<$str_length; $i++){
    if(ctype_space($arr[$i])){
        $res[$i] = 'space';
    }elseif(is_numeric($arr[$i])){
        $res[$i] = 'number';
    }elseif(is_string($arr[$i])){
        $regex = preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z\d]/', $arr[$i]);
        if($regex){
            $res[$i] = 'symbol';
        }else{
            $res[$i] = 'string';
        }
    }else{
        $res[$i] = "N/A";
    }
}
print_r($res);
```

Is there something better than this method?

Comment: Are those the four types of return values you expect to generate?  Do you need to support multibyte characters too?

Comment: It's not regex question, is rather about splitting string and determining what single character is..

Comment: @MichałTurczyn mainly yes these four types

Comment: @jibsteroos The question has been edited.  If you have DV'ed or V'edTC, you might consider whether the DV or CV is still appropriate.

Comment: Nope, not DV'ed or V'edTC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need regex for this.  The [`ctype_` functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ctype.php) will do the job for single-byte characters and it will be very easy to read (I cannot promise the same of my regex snippet).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0B1K0)) ([an implementation using your sample input](https://3v4l.org/mcVUa))

```
$tests = ['A', 'z', '+', '0', '8', '*', ' '];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo "\n{$test}: ";
    if (ctype_alpha($test)) {
        echo 'letter';
    } elseif (ctype_digit($test)) {
        echo 'number';
    } elseif (ctype_space($test)) {
        echo 'space';
    } else {
        echo 'symbol';
    }
}
```

---

And here is a demonstration of a regex that accommodates multibyte characters as well.

It is a minor adjustment to [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55992383/2943403).

To convert your input string to an array, just call `str_split()` (or `mb_str_split()`)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IAOfC))

```
$lookup = ['symbol', 'letter', 'number', 'space'];
$tests = ['A', 'z', '+', '0', 'ǻ', 'Ͱ', ' ', '₉'];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    $index = preg_match('~(\pL)|(\pN)|(\pZ)~u', $test, $out) ? array_key_last($out) : 0;
    echo "{$test}: {$lookup[$index]}\n";
}
```

Output

```
A: letter
z: letter
+: symbol
0: number
ǻ: letter
Ͱ: letter
 : space
₉: number
```

p.s. If you are not entertaining multibyte characters, then this pattern will do: `~([a-z])|(\d)|( )~i`